# SyntaxError with ImageField in Python Shell

Tags: python, django

I am learning forms on django documentation. I got stuck at ImageField. While doing the example it is reflecting Syntax Error
The code is exactly as mentioned by Django in documentation

Please advise what is wrong in it

```
from PIL import Image
from django import forms
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
     img = forms.ImageField()
file_data = {'img': SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', <file data>)}
form = ImageForm({}, file_data)
```

Please see the syntax error as represents in the python shell

```
file_data = {'img': SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', <file data>)}
  File "<console>", line 1
    file_data = {'img': SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', <file data>)}
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank You

Comment: That `<file data>` is just a placeholder there, instead of that you need to pass it some bytes like object.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for reply. Could you please elaborate how to get bytes object.

Comment: Try `SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', b'random_text_here')`, although this would likely result in an invalid form (As `b'random_text_here'` is not a proper image data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `file_data = {'img': SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', <file data>)}`, `<file data>` should be replaced with a bytes object.

If `test.png` is the image file, then you can replace the above line with

```
img_file = open('test.png', 'rb')
file_data = {'img': SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', img_file.read())}
img_file.close()
```

or

```
img_data = None
with open('test.png', 'rb') as img_file:
    img_data = img_file.read()

file_data = {'img': SimpleUploadedFile('test.png', img_data)}
```